# Critical section to disable SVC in ARM cortex R

Tags: assembly, arm, bare-metal

I would like to implement SVC protected critical section in a block of code like below:

```
key = SVC_disable();

... /* SVC protected critical block of code */

SVC_restore(key);
```

How to implement SVC_disable/restore on cortex R5 ARM

Additional details on code flow to clarify

This is a baremetal app running on ARM Cortex R5

Execution Path 1:

```
 Inst1
 Inst2

 /* ----- Start of SVC critical section -----*/
 Update  state atomically.
    -- Another SVC may also update same state so updates to state should prevent execution of any other SVC in the core

 /* ---- End of critical section ----*/
```

Now when control is in the critical section an interrupt may occur and the interrupt service routine can post a SVC that can corrupt state.

I dont want to disable IRQs/FIQs completely in the critical section. Only delay SVCs until Execution Path 1 leaves critical section

ANy posted SVC should be a pending exception which will get executed when Execution Path 1 leaves critical section

I see instructions to disable IRQ/FIQ but dont see any option to selectively disable SVC exception.

Comment: You trivially "disable" `svc` the same way you "disable" `ldr` or any other instruction which can raise a _synchronous_ exception. By not using it in that code sequence.

Comment: @Peter Cordes This is a baremetal application and has no OS

Comment: @Notlikethat There are interrupts in the system which could preempt existing code and the ISR can post a SVC. I dont want any SVC executed in the critical section.I am not asking about the current thread posting SVC which is tirivialy done by not invoking SVC instruction.

Comment: ...so disable interrupts selectively around just the state update? Set a flag when in the critical section to make the SVC handler bail out early? Tangentially, this is what the M-profile architecture has PENDSVC for; unfortunately that doesn't help on R-proifile.

Answer (score 2):

[`svc` is the user-space system-call instruction](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0179b/ar01s02s07.html).  So it can only happen if user-space code is running on the current core, right?  It doesn't happen asynchronously, and it doesn't make sense to have it disabled, because then what's supposed to happen when the `svc` instruction runs?

To avoid having user-space code (which could include `svc`) run while your kernel function is in a critical section, disable kernel preemption around your critical section, and don't sleep.  That's the only way user-space code could run on the same core that's in the middle of running some kernel code (AFAIK).

In Linux, [call `preempt_enable()` / `preempt_disable()`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/preempt-locking.txt).

Comment: Strictly it's not _just_ userspace - higher exception levels can use `svc` to call into themselves (vs. `hvc`/`smc` to go further up), but I don't think it's commonly done in practice, and the same "well don't do it then" principle would still apply.

Comment: @Peter Cordes Is there a way to delay exceptions until the critical section is exited.I have updated the question with additional details to make it clear what I am talking about

Comment: @Badri `svc` is synchronous. If the CPU is running code that includes an `svc` instruction, but "svc is disabled", what should happen? It can't run instructions after `svc` until after the svc handler has modified registers.  Do you want the CPU to go back to the code that's in the middle of the critical section and finish that, and then run the `svc` handler, and then return to the instruction after svc? How is all of that supposed to happen? TL:DR: don't use `svc` from interupt handlers if you need to avoid this problem, or else disable IRQs so you don't context switch in a critical section.